# Where is the log file for VLC media player on W10?

Tags: vlc-media-player

Ive got an error in VLC media player on a W10 pro machine and its prompting me to "CHeck the log for details".

Ive looked inside various VLC sub folders / progreamme files and searched for "vlc-log.txt" but i cant find the log file any ideas ?

Comment: Logging is not enabled by default: https://forum.videolan.org/viewtopic.php?t=148285

Answer (score 44, accepted):

You need to enable logging and set yourself the location and name of the
log file:

- Open menu *Tools > Preferences*
- Set at the bottom "Show settings" to "All"
- Click on the left *Advanced > Logger*
- Check "Log to file" and set the log file in "Log filename"
- Click Save
- Restart VLC for it to have effect.

Comment: BTW, I think you may have to restart VLC for these changes to take effect.

Comment: confirmed, **doesn't work without VLC restart**